# Firebase Authentication Error FirebaseAuthInvalidUserException

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a firebase project, in which I have enabled Email/Password Auth.

I created a user account in project and when I tried to login with android app, auth fails with this error :

```
FirebaseAuthInvalidUserException: There is no user record corresponding to this identifier. The user may have been deleted.
```

But am able to connect and display data from database as I have applied rule `read : true` . Still I need to make the auth works.

User is active, I have option to disable and delete the user.

Any idea why am getting this error?

Answer (score 2):

According to the docs :

> `FirebaseAuthInvalidUserException` thrown if the user account corresponding to email does not exist or has been disabled.

So check the email you enter in the email field.